# What is HTTP "Host" header?

Tags: http, http-headers

Given that the TCP connection is already established when the HTTP request is sent, the IP address and port are implicitly known -- a TCP connection is an IP + Port.

So, why do we need the `Host` header?  Is this only needed for the case where there are multiple hosts mapped to the IP address implied in the TCP connection?

Answer (score 260, accepted):

The [`Host`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-5.4) Header tells the webserver which *virtual host* to use (if set up). You can even have the same virtual host using several *aliases* (= domains and wildcard-domains). In this case, you still have the possibility to read that header manually in your web app if you want to provide different behavior based on different domains addressed. This is possible because in your webserver you can (and if I'm not mistaken you must) set up *one* vhost to be the default host. This default vhost is used whenever the `host` header does not match any of the configured virtual hosts.

That means: You get it right, although saying "multiple hosts" may be somewhat misleading: The host (the addressed machine) is the same, what really gets resolved to the IP address are different *domain names* (including subdomains) that are also referred to as *hostnames* (but not hosts!).

---

Although not part of the question, a fun fact: This specification led to problems with SSL in the early days because the web server has to deliver the certificate that corresponds to the domain the client has addressed. However, in order to know what certificate to use, the webserver should have known the addressed hostname in advance. But because the client sends that information only over the encrypted channel (which means: after the certificate has already been sent), the server had to assume you browsed the default host. That meant one SSL-secured domain per IP address / port-combination.

This has been overcome with [Server Name Indication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication); however, that again breaks some privacy, as the server name is now transferred in plain text again, so every man-in-the-middle would see *which hostname* you are trying to connect to.

Although the webserver would know the hostname from Server Name Indication, the `Host` header is not obsolete, because the Server Name Indication information is only used within the TLS handshake. With an unsecured connection, there is no Server Name Indication at all, so the `Host` header is still valid (and necessary).

Another fun fact: Most HTTP-server implementations (if not all) reject your HTTP request if it does not contain exactly one `Host` header, even if it could be omitted because there is only the default vhost configured. That means the minimum required information in an HTTP-(GET-)request is the first line containing `METHOD` `RESOURCE` and `PROTOCOL VERSION` and at least the `Host` header, like this:

```
GET /someresource.html HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
```

In the [MDN Documentation on the "Host" header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Host) they actually phrase it like this:

> A Host header field must be sent in all HTTP/1.1 request messages. A
> 400 (Bad Request) status code will be sent to any HTTP/1.1 request
> message that lacks a Host header field or contains more than one.

As mentioned by Darrel Miller, the complete specs can be found in [RFC7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-5.4).

Comment: *"Most webservers (if not all) reject your HTTP request if it does not contain exactly one `Host` header"* - That's a strict requirement of [RFC7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-5.4): *"A server MUST respond with a 400 (Bad Request) status code to any HTTP/1.1 request message that lacks a Host header field and to any request message that contains more than one Host header field or a Host header field with an invalid field-value."*

Comment: Well, yes. And I agree that all standard implementations actually do require the host header. However there are a lot of custom made servers out there for whatever purposes that might even answer your request without you sending the host header

Answer (score 60):

I would always recommend going to the authoritative source when trying to understand the meaning and purpose of HTTP headers.

> The "Host" header field in a request provides the host and port
> information from the target URI, enabling the origin server to
> distinguish among resources while servicing requests for multiple
> host names on a single IP address.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-5.4

Comment: So it just repeats the information that was already in the URI? seems pointless

Comment: @JuanPerez: No, the host name is not part of the IP or TCP header. While the target port is also in the TCP header, the host name is only in the HTTP 1.1 header fields, apart from TLS' Server Name Indication. You don't send the URI as-is in an HTTP request.