# 2 Identical IPs in Host File, Which Resolves First?

Tags: hosts

If I have in my **`hosts` file**

`127.0.0.1       localhost`

then at a later line I also have

`127.0.0.1       www.dev-environment.com`

**1. Which takes priority/resolves first?**

**2. What issues could I run into?**

Comment: To have to worry about that, you would need a way to put two URLs into a browser bar at the same time. Otherwise, if it is a programming-related question, what are you using to do the reverse lookup?

Comment: Hello Andrew, right now most computers at my company have 127.0.0.1 pointed to localhost of course. But we need to switch it to dev envrionment for a docker-compose setup, so I'm wondering if writing a script to add that line at the end will take priority over the localhost one. Any thoughts?

Comment: localhost *must* be set to 127.0.0.1 or else all sorts of things will break by default. There is no problem with adding other entries with the same IP address.

Comment: thanks Andrew, any idea which host the IP will choose first? the first or last in the file?

Comment: It translates the text to the IP address, not the other way round. Are you saying that you want two entries for, say, www.example.com with different IP addresses?

Comment: oh, so both `localhost` and `www.dev-legacy.com` will resolve to `127.0.0.1`, is this correct?

Comment: Yes. That is also (part of) how more than one web site can exist at the same IP address using [host headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43156023/what-is-http-host-header).