# Multiple websites in IIS pointing to same IP. How does IIS map to correct website?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-8

I have created two test websites in IIS. one is called testapp.com and other is called anothertestapp.com.

[image]

In my host files both testapp.com and anothertestapp.com is pointing to 127.0.0.1

both apps are loading perfectly in browser and show their respective contents.

The question however is, how does IIS knows that testapp.com is different than anothertestapp.com. I mean when in browser I type two different domains they both actually are pointing to same IP (127.0.0.1), how does IIS map that to two different websites correctly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is http host header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43156023/what-is-http-host-header)

Comment: nope, this is not duplicate. This is a separate question, however that thread will explain "host headers" in more detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When your browser loads a web page, one of the request headers it sends is the text of the domain name you typed in.  This is the "Host" request header.  IIS uses the value of this header to pick which web site will serve your request.  The "bindings" on your IIS web site let you configure its host headers.

Here's another question that explains the "Host" header in more detail:
[What is http host header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43156023/what-is-http-host-header)