# How can different subdomains point to the same IP and reach different webpages?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, a-records

I have a firebase project with 2 web applications:

```
name:      url
PC         pc-my-app.web.app
Mobile     m-my-app.web.app
```

firebase gives me the IP X.X.X.X for both applications.

I have a domain, example.com with the following records:

```
 A     example.com X.X.X.X
 A   m.example.com X.X.X.X
```

I thought that having these records pointing to the same IP would mean I see the same webpage, but that is clearly not the case.

Since ports are (apparently) never specified, how can the server on X.X.X.X tell which application I am trying to connect to?

My guess is that the server on X.X.X.X also recieves the original URL as a parameter somehow...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase Hosting (and most other hosting providers) check the `Host` header in the incoming request to determine what content to serve. And this `Host` header value allows a single server to map different requests to the correct web site content (often referred to as a "virtual host").

Also see:

- The [MDN documentation for `Host` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Host)
- [What is HTTP "Host" header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43156023/what-is-http-host-header)