# Http send post has no params

Tags: php, laravel

I have two app in Laravel. One is simple api with one controller if i send params using online tool or postman app everything is ok. i need check in headers to send 'Host' without this header i got error 400 Bad Request. But if i try send the same from my second laravel app i've got empty params request

```
$response = Http::asForm()->withHeaders([
    'Host' => 'example.com:8091',
])->post('http://example.com:8091/abc/test/', [
     'param_1' => 'abcdefgh123',
     'param2' => 'blablabla',
]);

$body = $response->getBody()->getContents();
```

I tried `asForm()` and nothing. What should be in Host header ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is HTTP "Host" header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43156023/what-is-http-host-header)

Comment: I will check with my local on live this could be my case

Answer (score 0):

Try this option

```
$json_data = json_encode(['param_1' => 'test 1', 'param_2' => 'test 2']);

$response = Http::asForm()->post('http://example.com:8091/abc/test/', [
    'body' => $json_data,
    'headers' => [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        'Content-Length' => strlen($json_data),
    ]
]);
```

Comment: still the same but i will try upload my local to server and than i will put real host

Comment: What errors are recorded in the logs with these requests?

Comment: No errors just request is ok but with empty params

Comment: Do you have a url structure with a slash at the end? Perhaps you need to remove the slash from the end. So that the redirect does not work, or the url parameters are correctly determined.