# PY4E: Can't retrieve file from the url link entered

Tags: python, http

SO community, please help!

I was doing the exercise 1 for chapter 12 of PY4E and could not figure out why the file wouldn't print out in terminal and I got the response of "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found"

[image: error]

Question: prompt the user for the URL so it can read any web page. You can use split('/') to break the URL into its component parts so you can extract the host name for the socket connect call. Add error checking using try and except to handle the condition where the user enters an improperly formatted or non-existent URL.

Code I wrote:

```
import socket

try: 
    url = input('Enter URL here: ')
    new_url = url.split('/')
    host = new_url[2]
    path = '/' + '/'.join(new_url[3:]) 
    #print(new_url)
    #print(host)
    #print(path)

    mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    mysock.connect((host, 80))
    cmd = f'GET {path} HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n'.encode()
    mysock.send(cmd)

    while True:
            data = mysock.recv(512)
            if len(data) < 1:
                break
            print(data.decode(),end='')

    mysock.close()
except:
    print('url not found or has issue')
```

The url that i'm trying to retreive: http://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt   - the link can be opened in the browser so I'm very confused that it returned 404 not found

Comment: First drop this `try`-`except` block to see the real error. To cite the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/): "When catching exceptions, mention specific exceptions whenever possible instead of using a bare `except:` clause"

Comment: Yes I dropped the try - except block but it still returns 404 :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `Host` HTTP header, which is used [to distinguish between different virtual hosts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43156023/what-is-http-host-header) hosted on the same machine.

Comment: As far as I understand, host = new_url[2]  already grabbed the host, and then mysock.connect() will open the connection. Do I understand it incorrectly? If so, could you show me how to update the code? Thanks!

Comment: `mysock.connect` will resolve the domain name you give it and connect to an IP address, and the server has no idea which name you used - it just knows which IP address was used contact it. So the name is also sent in the [`Host` header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-5.4) so the server is able to know which of the many sites hosted on it you're trying to reach.

Comment: Thank you Taavi, with some reading and trying I was able to get the file print out

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who encounters the same issue as me, the cmd line of the code should be:

```
cmd = f'GET {path} HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: {host}\r\n\r\n'.encode()
```

Explanation below:

Host: is an HTTP header field that specifies the domain name of the server (the host). This header is required in HTTP/1.1 requests, as it indicates which host on the server should handle the request. This is important for servers that host multiple domains (virtual hosting).

{host} is a placeholder for the actual hostname of the server you're connecting to.