# C code implementing DNS returns invalid IP addresses

Tags: c, http, dns, ip

I'm executing this code from Github which queries a user-provided domain name and implements DNS:

https://gist.github.com/fffaraz/9d9170b57791c28ccda9255b48315168

When I run the program it asks for a host, so I give it `edition.cnn.com`

I get this response:

```
Enter Hostname to Lookup : edition.cnn.com
Resolving edition.cnn.com
Sending Packet...Done
Receiving answer...Done
The response contains : 
 1 Questions.
 4 Answers.
 0 Authoritative Servers.
 0 Additional records.


Answer Records : 4 
Name : edition.cnn.com has IPv4 address : 151.101.3.5
Name : edition.cnn.com has IPv4 address : 151.101.67.5
Name : edition.cnn.com has IPv4 address : 151.101.131.5
Name : edition.cnn.com has IPv4 address : 151.101.195.5

Authoritive Records : 0 

Additional Records : 0
```

However, when I enter the first IP address in to a web browser, it's not a valid webpage.

Is this expected? How do you know which of the responses is the correct/working one?

Answer (score 1):

Those are the right IP adresses. check it out : https://dnschecker.org/#A/edition.cnn.com

The error you get when accessing directly by the IP is a common name mismatch.
A common name mismatch error occurs when the common name or SAN of a SSL/TLS Certificate does not match the domain or address bar in the browser. It is a security feature to help prevent phishing.

Answer (score 1):

There is no one-to-one correspondence between web sites and IP addresses.

Not only (as you have already found out) edition.cnn.com is visible via many different IP addresses, but also, each one of those IP addresses may host a myriad of web sites, which in turn means that in many cases, you cannot just direct your browser to an IP address and expect to see a particular web site, or any web site.

Every HTTP request is supposed to contain a "HOST" header, (see Stack Overflow: [What is HTTP "Host" header?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43156023/773113)) which is supposed to contain the name of the host to which the request was addressed. This was an afterthought deemed necessary because the path after the GET verb is relative to the root of the host and does not include the host name. For example, `GET / HTTP/1.1`.

So:

- If you type https://edition.cnn.com in the address bar of your
  browser, then the HOST field will contain this host name, so the
  server that eventually receives this request knows which site it is
  meant for, among many sites that it may be hosting on the same IP
  address.
- However, when you tell your browser to visit an IP address, then the
  HOST field is either blank, or contains the IP address
  that you typed, so the server has no way of knowing which host
  the request was intended for, and thus has no option but to fail the request.